# How to properly pause/stop a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I've been working on a chat client in C#. I am trying to figure out a way to pause/stop a thread when disconnecting to the server. Right now when I click on disconnect it should send off a {quit} message to the server, but after that the client just locks up because the receiving thread is still running, trying to receive data from the server when it is disconnected. Does anybody know a good way to handle this?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;


namespace sockjtest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
        string readData = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        // send from sendbox
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendbox.Text);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            sendbox.Clear();           
        }

        private void recievebox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        // send username to server once connected
        private void sendusr()
        {

            byte[] userStream = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(usernamebox.Text);
            serverStream.Write(userStream, 0, userStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

        }

        // connect button

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(recievestream);

            if (conntectbutton.Text.Contains("Connect") == true)
            {



                string srvip = serverip.Text;
                int srvport = Convert.ToInt32(serverport.Text);
                try
                {
                    clientSocket.Connect(srvip, srvport);
                    if (clientSocket.Connected)
                    {

                        // change button state
                        conntectbutton.Text = "Disconnect";
                        recievebox.Clear();
                        recievebox.AppendText("*** Connected to " + srvip + ":" + srvport + " ***\r\n");

                        // start recieve thread
                        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                        ctThread.Start();
                        // call send user function
                        sendusr();

                    }

                }

                catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
                {
                    recievebox.Clear();
                    recievebox.AppendText("*** Could not connected to " + srvip + ":" + srvport + " ***");
                }
            } else
            {
                string quitmsg = "{quit}";
                byte[] quitstream = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(quitmsg);
                serverStream.Write(quitstream, 0, quitstream.Length);
                serverStream.Flush();

                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                ctThread.Abort();

                conntectbutton.Text ="Connect";
            }


        }

        private void serverip_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void serverport_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // recieve
        private void recievestream()
        {
            while (true)
            {


                NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                int buffSize = 0;
                byte[] inStream = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream, 0, bytesRead);
                readData = "" + returndata;
                msg();

            }
        }

        // print message to recievebox
        private void msg()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));
            else
                recievebox.Text = recievebox.Text + Environment.NewLine + readData;
        }

        private void usernamebox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a threading problem; you have a protocol design problem.  You should design the communication protocol to handle this situation.  Like before shutdown the server sends a final message to the client.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This fixed it, thanks!!

Comment: @MichaelL - Just a small note to keep in mind - you should never ever ever call `Thread.Abort()` unless you are trying to crash out of your program.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah I read about that, I've remove it!

Answer (score 0):

change `while(true)` to `while(clientSocket.Connected)`  then, when remote server disconnected the connection, your loop will automatically break;

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with making the server send back the {quit} message back to the client. When received it will close the socket and then re-initialize it so it is possible to reconnect back to the server.